# Databases: How to deal with associations? N+1 select problem, inconsistent reads, and more

Tags: database-design

How do you model associations without running into the [N+1 selects problem](http://www.pramatr.com/blog/2009/02/05/sql-n-1-selects-explained/) or [inconsistent reads problem](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.554728.8)?

#### Example

A building contains a series of rooms. Each room contains multiple people. The last person to leave the room has to close the door :) Each person is associated with a large profile image which is accessed infrequently. I use the following schema:

```
Room[id, name, numberOfPeople]
Image[id, data]
People[id, name, room_id, image_id]
```

Typically I define [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) methods for each table and implement the [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) on terms of these methods. For example, if the application asks for a list of people and their associated room I implement it as follows:

```
class ServiceLayer
{
  Map<Person, Room> getPeople(List<Long> peopleIds)
  {
    List<Person> people = peopleCrud.getById(peopleIds); // first query
    List<Person, Room> result = new ArrayList<Person, Room>();
    for (Person person: people)
    {
      // second query (repeated N times)
      Room room = roomCrud.getById(person.getRoomId());
      result.put(person, room);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

This approach suffers from the N+1 problem because if I ask for information on N persons I end up with N+1 queries. It also suffers from the inconsistent reads problem, as follows:

1. Thread 1 runs the first query, gets back a list of people.
2. Thread 2 updates a person's room (updating room_id and decreasing the old room's `numberOfPeople`).
3. Thread 1 runs the second query, gets back the person's old room
4. Thread 1 now thinks that the person is still in the old room but numberOfPeople does not include him (oops!). I am expecting numberOfPeople of the old room to include the person, or for the person to show up in the new room.

I can only think of two possible solutions:

1. Have the CRUD load up all associations eagerly. This has the downside of loading the profile image even though it is very large and is used infrequently. This approach suffers from poor performance when dealing with highly-connected objects (loading unused data or more data than will fit into memory).
2. Have the Service Layer talk directly to the database (remove the CRUD layer) so it can retrieve as little or as much of the object graph as it needs using SQL joins to prevent inconsistent reads.

What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do you model associations without running into the N+1 selects problem or inconsistent reads problem?

The inconsistent reads problem happens with any relational database.  Any one can read a row that then is changed by another thread.  The only way to minimize this problem is to read the data as close to processing it as possible.

Which leads to the N+1 selects problem.

In your example, you're assuming that the browsing thread reads the old version of the room row.  This will depend on exactly how the database handles write locks and read locks.  This is dependent on which database we're talking about.

If it's important that your browses are always accurate, then you have to choose the most restrictive read locks your database offers.  This level of lock control is where databases like Oracle and DB2 show their value over MySQL.

Comment: @Gilbert, I understand your answer regarding inconsistent reads but I don't understand which part of your answer addresses the N+1 selects problem. The section about locks seems to be addressing inconsistent reads. Please clarify.

Comment: @Gili:  The most restrictive read locks minimizes both the inconsistent reads problem and the N + 1 selects problem.  If you have a restrictive read lock, no one can update the row while you're processing it.

Comment: @Gilbert, please provide links to documentation of the lock types you had in mind (even if it's database-specific).

Comment: @Gili:  Here's an explanation of the 4 types of read locks (isolation) in DB2 - http://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/java/db2-locking-and-concurrency-for-java-developers.html

Comment: @Gilbert, okay that would work. What you think of the second option mentioned in the question (have the service layer talk directly to the database)?

Comment: @Gili: The second option is good, as it separates the database logic (model) from the view and the controller code.  Remember, you want to perform any selects as close as possible to any changes to the selected information.